# Offline form/Data entry for SharePoint Data Entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, offline

I need some solution, where user need to do audit of a assembly plant and fill the checklist and write-down findings.

I was planning to build this solution on SharePoint, but the challenge is the plant has no network.
So I need a solution where user can fill the form offline mode and once it comes online the data get updated into the sharepoint online list and library(click images)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Building fast, offline-capable Microsoft 365 web applications](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/building-fast-offline-capable-microsoft-365-web-applications/ba-p/2999229).

> Building fast, fluid Microsoft 365 web applications is one of our core focus areas on the SharePoint engineering team. Over the course of this year, we’ve double-downed on performance – making our web apps load faster, delivering up to a 57% improvement in page interactivity, along with the ability to work with data offline. We’re pleased to announce we’ve reached general availability for Microsoft Lists customers. The focus of this article is to share how it all works and how we went about designing and developing it.

> And we didn’t stop there. Our ambition is to deliver experiences that are consistently fast for every user on all kinds of networks and devices – even when there is no connection to the Internet. To help us accomplish this, we looked beyond the fundamentals to unlock new levels of web performance and enable new ways for our customers to experience Microsoft 365 web applications. We do this by blending Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) and expanding Project Nucleus.

[image]